# ios: predict if two annotation views would overlap each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm developing some `MKMapView` logic. There are many annotations on my map view. I need to compose few locations in one if those annotation views would overlap each other, and display Annotation view with changes. So I should predict that case, and I need to determinate that only from annotations' location properties and current `MKMapView`'s zoom.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAlert:(CoordinatesAlert *)alert1 beInGroupWithAlert:(CoordinatesAlert *)alert2 {
    // somehow calculate current map view zoom
    CGFloat zoom = ...
    if ([alert1.location distanceFromLocation:alert2.location] / zoom < kSomeCoeficient) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Also I worried about this solution because I need to reload annotations and those views on every zoom change.

How can I do this in better way? Is there any default solution for annotation views clustering?

Comment: Libraries exist such as [OCMapView](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView) or [kingpin](https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin). Those may not be the best, but have a look around Google and you'll find something that suits your needs.

Comment: What is CoordinatesAlert ?

Comment: @DavidAnsermot just some model that contains location for displaying

Comment: @rdurand yes, I am going to check those sources, but I think that libraries are not so flexeble for my purposes, maybe I will not be able to customize them. UI is going to be too complex, custom callout views that display in different way depends on annotations count, and other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of exist libraries do not suit for my needs, they all works with areas but I need to group annotations only if they would be overlapped. Also I do not need so many annotations, so i do not need performance optimization.
So, I've found some solution, it is better then nothing.

```
- (BOOL)isViewForLocation:(CLLocation *)location1 overlappedByViewForLocation:(CLLocation *)location2 {
    const CLLocationDegrees deltaLatitude = ABS(location1.coordinate.latitude - location1.coordinate.latitude);
    const CLLocationDegrees deltaLongitude = ABS(location2.coordinate.longitude - location2.coordinate.longitude);
    const CLLocationDegrees mapAreaLatitude = self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta;
    const CLLocationDegrees mapAreaLongitude = self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta;

    return (deltaLatitude / mapAreaLatitude) < (kAnnotationTapArea.size.height / self.mapView.frame.size.height)
    && (deltaLongitude / mapAreaLongitude) < (kAnnotationTapArea.size.width / self.mapView.frame.size.width);
}
```